# two array multipication in a method

Tags: java, arrays, jcreator

I need to compute the multiplication of the `grade[0]` to `percentage1[0]` and then print the result. Can someone help me?

### LaboratoryExam.java

```
import java.util.*; 
public class LaboratoryExam {

  static Scanner glad=new Scanner(System.in);
  static double grades[]=new double[5];
  static double percentage1[]=new double[5];
  static double comp[]=new double[5];
  static double sum=0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {



    System.out.print("Enter 5 grades: ");

    for(int i=0; i<grades.length; i++){

      grades[i]=glad.nextDouble();
    }


    Percentage();
    compute(grades,percentage1);
    System.out.println("\nSum is: " + sum);
  }

  public static double[] Percentage(){
    double Percentage;
    System.out.print("\nEnter 5 Percentage: ");

    for(int p=0; p<percentage1.length; p++)
      percentage1[p]=glad.nextDouble();

    return percentage1;
  }

  public static double compute(  double[] grades,  double[] percentage1 ){

    for(int i=0; i<comp.length;i++){

      double comp=grades[0]*percentage1[1];
      System.out.println("Equivalent: "+sum);
      double sum=comp+comp;
    }
    return sum;
  }

}
```

Comment: in your `compute` method, `grades[0]*percentage1[1];` should be `grades[i]*percentage1[i];`

Comment: Not part of the problem, though worth mentioning: variables and method should start with a lower case, classes with an upper case. [Example](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

Comment: sir @LuiggiMendoza.. the output is still zero both the equivalent and the sum..pls help me sir.. thank you

Comment: @GladwynRomines: you should define `sum` before the loop. And `sum = comp + comp` won't work, try `sum += comp`

Comment: thanks everyone! i really appreciate the help..and i got it.. :) the only thing which is the problem now is the System.out.println("Sum: "+sum); in the main method.. because the output of the sum is still zero...

Comment: I got it now..what i did is in the compute method i used void..haha.. so that no value will return to main.. :) easy as that.. :) thanks so much to all who helped.. :) Godbless!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost good. Make sure you declare the sum variable outside of the `for` loop so you can retain its value on each iteration of the loop. Also use your array indices to access the correct values. Change it to this:

```
public static double compute(  double[] grades,  double[] percentage1 ){
  double sum = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<comp.length;i++){

    comp[i]=grades[i]*percentage1[i];
    System.out.println("Equivalent: "+comp[i]);
    sum += comp[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Also, in your main method, make it:

```
sum = compute(grades,percentage1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `compute` method, you're getting the product of `grades[0]` and `percentage1[1]` for all the iterations. Instead, you should use the elements on the `i` index as stated in your  `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<comp.length;i++) {
    double comp = grades[i]*percentage1[i];
```

Also, you're calculating the wrong sum:

```
for(int i=0; i<comp.length;i++) {
    double sum=comp+comp;
}
```

Here you're shadowing the `static double sum` declared before, so you will always get 0 when doing `return sum;`. You should instead use the `sum` variable declared in your class:

```
for(int i=0; i<comp.length;i++) {
    //note: no re-declaration of sum variable
    //also fixed the sum calculation
    sum += comp;
}
```

In the end, your code will look like:

```
for(int i=0; i<comp.length;i++) {
    double comp=grades[i]*percentage1[i];
    comp[i] = comp;
    sum += comp;
    System.out.println("Equivalent: "+sum);
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the multiplication with `grades[i]` and `percentage1[i]`. Here you're just multiplying the same number over and over. Try this:

```
double comp=grades[i]*percentage1[i];
```

Also, I think you're not printing the right thing, since you seem to want to print the result of the multiplication. Try with this:

```
System.out.println("Equivalent: "+ comp);
```

Finaly, I think it would be better to declare comp and sum out of the for:

```
public static double compute(  double[] grades,  double[] percentage1 ){
    double comp;
    double sum;
    for(int i=0; i<comp.length;i++){
        comp=grades[0]*percentage1[1];
        System.out.println("Equivalent: "+sum);
        sum=comp+comp;
    }
    return sum;
}
```